# Unable to access _geometry variable in fragment shader

Tags: scenekit, fragment-shader

I'm attempting to simulate a depth map in SceneKit and I'm pretty new to 3D programming.  I've created a triangle mesh in XY with the ocean depth in Z.  the plan is to use the fragment shader to scale this Z-value between colors to create a nice map

In the documentation for the shaders, it says the values from previous shaders are available in later shaders.  In particular, the first (geometry) shader has a structure named _geometry which contains the vertex in model space.  however, for some reason in my fragment shader it is not defined and I get an error when I try to use it.

The error output from the failed compile shows other values -are- available, such as _surface and _light, but no _geometry.

I've attempted to transform from the _surface.position vec3 back to model space, but I'm afraid I'm out of my depth with the transforms.  According to the documents this value is in view space, so I've tried:

```
vec4 model4 = vec4(_surface.position, 1.0);
vec4 model_position = u_inverseModelViewTransform * model4;
if (model_position.z .....
```

but this isn't giving my the correct values of Z.  u_inverseModelViewProjectionTransform does not appear to exist, either.

I've also tried writing a geometry shader that did nothing just to ensure _geometry was present in that shader and hoping that having the geometry shader would include _geometry in my fragment shader but no joy

My question is:  how do I get to the _geometry variable in my fragment shader or, absent that, how do I transform _surface.position back to model space?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `_geometry` struct is only available in the vertex shader.

The documentation seem to indicate that `u_inverseModelViewProjectionTransform` should exist as a uniform variable, but I've not been able to use it either.

As a workaround I've been using something like the following in fragment shaders to go from view to model space.

```
vec4 model_position = u_inverseModelTransform * u_inverseViewTransform * model4;
```

**edit:**

Xcode doesn't seem to dump the entire SceneKit shader when compilation fails anymore, fortunately you can still see the full code via the GPU debugging UI. Turns out you also have access to the `commonprofile_node` struct in the fragment shader. *The following is a better solution.*

```
vec4 model_position = scn_node.inverseModelViewTransform * model4;
```

Good luck!

Comment: The first suggestion worked to get back to the proper Z value.  I tried the second, but got an error about scn_node not being defined.  Maybe it isn't defined in a SceneKit shader?.  I didn't know about the GPU debugging UI - I'm assuming it's only available when your running on a device.  thanks.

Comment: Urgh, you're right, just tried to run the second solution in the simulator... it doesn't work. It's a Metal vs OpenGL issue; SceneKit has a different shader for each 3D graphics framework. The Metal SceneKit shader has the `scn_node` struct in the fragment shader whereas the OpenGL (as used by simulator) doesn't.